# Why are my kitties merchants, engineers and managers?

Tags: kittens-game

My kittens have those names of professions to their right. What do they mean? Do they confer bonus to certain areas?

Comment: It means nothing atm.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the changelog: `Senators and leader can be assigned, unassigned and promoted based on exp (no effect yet)` - this applies also to the professions. It will be fully implemented in a future update.